# How to create recipe from sourcebranch other than master using recipetool?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I tried using `recipetool` to create a bitbake recipe as follows to avoid pulling from `master` (the default) and use `main` instead:

```
build$ recipetool create -B main  https://github.com/Maillol/aiohttp-pydantic.git
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
ERROR: branch= parameter and -B/--srcbranch option cannot both be specified - use one or the other
```

What am I doing wrong?

Apart form that I'm wondering if `create` shouldn't always pull from the default branch and add that specifically to the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with devtool?

The manual[1] says:

```
devtool add --srcbranch honister jackson /home/user/sources/jackson
```

[1] https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/devtool-reference.html#adding-a-new-recipe-to-the-workspace-layer

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! That leads to the same issue:
```
 devtool add --srcbranch main python3-pydantic-aiohttp https://github.com/Maillol/aiohttp-pydantic.git \n
NOTE: Starting bitbake server... \n
ERROR: branch= parameter and -B/--srcbranch option cannot both be specified - use one or the other
```

Comment: Which yocto version do you use?

Comment: I'm on branch `dunfell` and `BitBake Build Tool Core version 1.46.0`

Comment: I have a more recent version (closer to master) and it seems to do something. This is what I did: https://pastebin.com/Ss1HFtby and this is what it produced: https://pastebin.com/ZDvsMste

Comment: I assume it's fixed in `master` but not backported. I'll see if I find the time to debug that later. Thanks so much for your input!

Comment: As a follow-up could you kindly have a look at this surprising failure when trying to build the recipe? It appears to try to import from the target package during installation and I don't understand why. https://pastebin.com/nf0FY9sZ

Comment: one problem seems to be this: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'